# 500 error on inserting data into BigQuery with API into date-partitioned table

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I trying to insert data into BigQuery table with partitioning.
And I always get error:

```
"errors": [
         {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "internalError",
            "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."
         }
```

When I create this table withour partitioning - everything works fine.
When I create smaller table with 27 column - everything works fine.
But when I try to insert more columns - I get this error.

Here is my schema and my code:

```
[
  {"name":"timestamp", "type": "timestamp", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"feid", "type": "string", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"sid", "type": "string", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"remote_addr", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"url", "type": "string", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"url_hostname", "type": "string", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"url_uri", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"referrer", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"referrer_hostname", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"device_ratio", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"device_screen_size", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"device_window_size", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"timer_start", "type": "integer", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"timer_init", "type": "integer", "mode": "required"},
  {"name":"user_timezone", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"user_lang", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"nats_code_id", "type": "integer", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"nats_sess", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"ua_os", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"ua_os_version", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"ua_browser", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"ua_browser_version", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"ua_device", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"ua_device_type", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"date_day", "type": "integer", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"date_week", "type": "integer", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"date_month", "type": "integer", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"date_year", "type": "integer", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"geoip_continent", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"geoip_country", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"geoip_region", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"geoip_city", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"geoip_latitude", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"geoip_longitude", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"networkname", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"pagetype", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"pageid", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"templatetype", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"locale", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"},
  {"name":"zone", "type": "string", "mode": "nullable"}
]
```

bq mk --schema=pageviews_v3.json --time_partitioning_type=DAY test.pv3

```
    $rows = [];
    $data = [
    [
     [
      "timestamp" => "2016-09-21 19:57:56",
      "feid" => "safdhiasgih4",
      "sid" => "heghu549023",
      ...
      "zone" => "NONAUTHORIZED",
     ],
     [
      "timestamp" => "2016-09-21 19:44:17",
      "feid" => "agihgu43q92",
      "sid" => "sadfnogsiuphi243",
      ...
      "zone" => "NONAUTHORIZED",
     ]
    ]

];
            foreach ($data as $item) {
                $row = new \Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
                $row->setJson($item);
                $row->setInsertId(uniqid());
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

    $service = new \Google_Service_Bigquery($this->client);
            $request = new \Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest;
            $request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
            $request->setRows($rows);
```

What can couse this error ? How can I get more detail about this error ?

Comment: Can you provide the project id and job id so we can take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, poised-resource-121617, Thank you!

Comment: And now there are always 400 errors:
   error: '{
    "error": {
       "errors": [
        {
           "domain": "global",
           "reason": "invalid",
           "message": "No rows present in the request.",
           "locationType": "other",
           "location": "rows"
        }
       ],
       "code": 400,
       "message": "No rows present in the request."
    }

Comment: The 500 errors are usually backend timeouts. Retry would normally fix the problem.

Are you using the same code snippet when you get the 400 error? It does seem that you're setting data in the rows.

Comment: We've foind the answer - some chinese symbols in utf8. we removed them and everything works fine.

Comment: Good to know that you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: If you found the solution, please post is as an answer, this would be helpful for others as well!

Were the chinese symbols in your data or in your queries? How did you find them? etc...